# Report display nothing but blank pages when published

Tags: crystal-reports

My web application runs fine locally but when published the reports are nothing but blank pages. When I check the page elements using F12 button, there are four errors:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
http://crystalreportviewers13//js/crviewer/crv.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
MasterSection.aspx:64 Uncaught ReferenceError: bobj is not defined
MasterSection.aspx:73 Uncaught ReferenceError: bobj is not defined
```

How can I resolve these errors?

Comment: I would check here. Bobj is probably the main reason you're getting a blank report: http://scn.sap.com/community/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio/blog/2011/01/12/how-do-i-resolve-bobj-is-undefined-issue

Comment: @4444 Please post your comment as an answer, because i just wanted to answer but  it will be the same as you with the same link ! I'd like to upvote you. Regards

Comment: @Furtiro Can do, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*Bobj is not defined* is almost certainly the reason your report is coming back blank. There are a few possible causes for the issue, but there's a solution to each. To paraphrase [this article](http://scn.sap.com/community/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio/blog/2011/01/12/how-do-i-resolve-bobj-is-undefined-issue) there are four likely causes:

> **1. The *crystalreportviewers12* folder is missing:** Copy the folder *crystalreportviewers12* from `C:Inetpubwwwrootsystem_web2_0_50727` from *Default Website* to *Custom Website* in IIS. Or point a virtual directory to the *aspnet_client* folder in your directory.
>
> **2. The Application Pool is running under Integrated Mode when IIS 7 is used:** Select the Application Pool in the IIS Manger and go to Basic Settings. Under Managed Pipeline Mode, change Integrated Mode to Classic Mode.
>
> **3. Wrong value assigned to the *resourceURI* key:** Change it to  `~/crystalreportviewers12` instaed of `/crystalreportviewers12`
>
> **4. The error occurs in the development machine because the .NET Framework can't find files needed by Report Viewer:** Copy *CrystalReportViewers12* from `C:Program FilesBusiness ObjectsCommon4.0` and paste it to `C:WindowsMicrosoft.NETFrameworkv3.5ASP.NETClientFiles`.

Your directories and framework might be slightly different if you're using an newer version of VS.